# Ember-data 0.14, setting belongsTo does not dirty the record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have recently upgraded to ember-data 0.14 and setting a belongsTo relationship no longer dirties the record.

Say I have:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  surname: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    surname: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
});
```

If I have a contact and change the user, isDirty is false:

e.g.

```
contact.set('user', newUser);
contact.get('isDirty'); //false
```

I created [this](http://jsbin.com/isunaf/12/edit) jsbin but it works with the fixture adapter.

I am using the RESTAdapter and it does not work.

I am wondering if this is anything to do with the observer changes in ember 1.0?

If I roll the code back to rc7 and 0.14 the exact same code works so something in 1.0 is stopping the change being registered.

What happens when a belongsTo is set in ember-data?  Where in the code should I be looking?

Comment: there was a discussion about that on IRC this afternoon. An issue has been filled too: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1367

Comment: Can you give me any indication of where I can start looking in the code?

Comment: I don't know what the 0.14 version of ember-data is. Could you give me the corresponding commit ? Anyway, I just saw the comment of @wycats in github, and perhaps we could find a way to workaround your need for isDirty here ?

Comment: He is talking about ember-data beta and strangely he is saying that changing a belongsTo record won't  dirty the record.  I think he is saying a non dirty record will still be pushed to the server.

The problem is that if I run 0.14 (https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/d9cd2701a1f457b293f8afaa59f55b8ff9020a61) against ember rc7 then the record is dirtied.  Against ember 1.0 it is not.

We are in beta with a product and this is causing huge headaches.  

I would be interested to find out where in the code (v0.14) that a record should be dirtied if a belongsTo property is changed.

Comment: Oh ok, apologies for my long time reaction. So 0.14 is before the merge of jj-abrams, so I think it should definitely work as you expect. I take a look at this right now.

Comment: Sir, I owe you a drink.  It works fine with ember rc7.  It might be something to do with the observer changes in rc8/1.0.

Comment: For now, I think the starting point may be here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v0.14/packages/ember-data/lib/system/relationships/belongs_to.js#L105 .As you suspect an observer change (which I agree) it may be a good thing to check if this code is executed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38090/discussion-between-dagda1-and-sly7-7)

Comment: @sly7_7 I got to the bottom of it.  Check the answer.  This was a real head scratcher :).

Answer (score 2):

After much digging about, it turned out to be a problem with suspendListeners that is fixed in [this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/d034d11591eb68be88021004e5f3de5c4cc0f4ba) commit with Ember.

Comment: So a big +1. The first thing I should have said "Did you try with master". And you were right, it was a problem with the listeners... Ember is great, ember-data too IMO, but unfortunately, it seems that all hard bugs are on you :(

Comment: I should have tried master also.  

I am using ember and ED in a big, real app.  It has been a fairly rough road with every upgrade.  I don't think I am upgrading for a while.

Comment: That's the same for us :), almost two years with ember now... with hapiness and pain. But I would not go out of ember in any way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I'm using ember/ember-data master in my project and have verified that the code in the commit being called. However the object with the belongs to property is still clean after the belongs to property is changed.

Comment: This is to do with the 0.14 tag.

I believe that changing belongsTo in the new ember data master does not dirty the object and this is intentional.

I think you can still save objects that are not dirty in the master.

This is not the case in the 0.14 tag.

Comment: +1, updating fixed that issue for me. Ember 1.2.0 with ember-data 0.13